# Does Unity3d IBM Cloudant wrapper exist?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, ibm-cloud, nosql

I was exploring different storage solutions for my Unity app:

1. C# code communicates with PHP script on server and this php script communicates with SQL database on server. It was good, but writing Universal PHP script was hard and we ended up with many different php scripts for different queries. It wasn't a flexible solution.
2. AWS - we decided to try DynamoDB, it was ok - Amazon provided nice UnityPackage with elegant wrapper for integrating our code with their back end; however their solution is expensive and it doesn't provide much more then a storage space.
3. IBM Bluemix- now we're investigating Bluemix solution. It provides many interesting add-ons like Watson, and we think we would like to stay with it. However it seems like no one have ever bothered to create some integration points with Unity, and it seems like all communications needs to go through REST api.

Does anybody have some experience with IBM cloud solution, and could provide some tips for integrating an existing project / redesigning it to work best with IBM?

Thanks !

Comment: FYI Adam, everyone just uses back4app (ie, Parse), or Firebase, PubNub etc, or aws (which as you say can be expensive), Gamesparks, and so on.  (just google something like "BAAS for Unity3D").  Note that Unity are releasing their OWN baas soon - that will be the only realistic option.

Comment: Consuming REST api with unity is so easy, you can simply use WWW class or Assetstore packages for REST api's. if IBM has REST API's then your good to go.